# How do I fix problem synching with github on second PC?

Tags: github, synchronization, tortoisegit

I use private repositories on github and can access these quite successfully from my development PC and from some Azure VMs.  I do not do anything at commend line.  I do everything via TortoiseGit.  These are all running windows 10.
On my second PC I used to be able to pull and push, but now it keeps asking ffor github login details, but it rejects these as invalid.  I can log into github itself from the PC with the same user name and password.  Any idea how I can synch with githib again on this PC ?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub recently disabled password login for Git actions. YOu need to use a special app token.